# Can not resolve symbol ObservableMap<String,Object>

Tags: android, android-databinding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="android.databinding.ObservableMap"/>
        <variable name="user" type="ObservableMap<String,Object>"/>//there is the problem!!!!!!!!
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text='@{user["lastName"]}'
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:text="button"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Android Studio ：2.3.1
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

I am using [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).Android Studio says that **Can not resolve symbol ObservableMap<String, Object>**.Everything is fine if I use ObservableMap instead of ObservableMap<String, Object>

So..what is wrong with it?Am I using wrong version of AS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. IDE might show error in xml file for this but it should run fine.

```
<data>
    <variable name="user" type="ObservableMap&lt;String,Object&gt;"/>
</data>
```

Comment: hi @Sifat Oshan.To begin with,I use the code like ["ObservableMap&lt;String,Object&gt;"]...but this this code display in red in Android Studio.It feels that it is not right,so I started to use code in my question and it can not run.And I try your answer again,it run!Thank you..